# SharePoint 2016 On-Premises: Retrieving and Comparing Items using jQuery

Tags: sharepoint-server, javascript, jquery, calendar, sharepoint-calendar

I am trying to catch double booking when people create events on a calendar in SharePoint 2016.

Using the PreSaveAction function, I want to retrieve the current item being created and then do a for loop and compare the current item to each existing event already on the calendar using jQuery.

I would want to retrieve three columns for each item:

- Location
- Start Time
- End Time

I am doing this through the NewForm.aspx using the script editor web part.

I have never used Javascript or Jquery before so please note such.

Thanks,

Colton

Answer (score 0):

You could refer steps in below article to have a test:

https://spjsblog.com/2012/02/25/spjs-resource-management-no-more-double-booking/

Comment: Already looked at that link plenty. Not really useful to me.